# fish: multiple commands in a single line

Tags: fish

The following commands (fish version 2.7.1) work flawlessly when I run them in the command line one after another

```
converter_to_csv *.ods
cat *.csv >> data.csv
```

But when I tried to combine them in a single line

```
converter_to_csv *.ods; and cat *.csv >> data.csv
```

They ended up with an error:

```
fish: No matches for wildcard “*.csv”. See `help expand`.
```

I read Globbing and Wildcards chapters, but could not find a clear explanation of how to deal with this.

I also tried put this commands in a script file

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
converter_to_csv *.ods
cat *.csv >> data.csv
```

which produces the same error.

What do I do wrongly?

Comment: I suppose the csv files don't exist until the converter is done.

Comment: @glennjackman I supposed this should have been resolved by `and` combiner.

Comment: I don't know at what point fish is trying to expand the glob. Apparently it's "now" when it should be "after the semicolon". Would need people expert in fish internals.

Comment: There's no difference between separating commands with a newline or semicolon. If `*.csv` expands to nothing, it means that there were no .csv files in the directory at the time the command was run. What you can do is run the `converter_to_csv` command, and then see what's in the directory.

Comment: Confirmed: `ls *.csv` when there are no csv files emits the error, and then `touch file.csv; and ls *.csv` does not.

Answer (score 1):

This paragraph in `help expand` is relevant here:

> Note that for most commands, if any wildcard fails to expand, the command is not executed, $status is set to nonzero, and a warning is printed. This behavior is consistent with setting `shopt -s failglob` in bash. There are exactly 4 exceptions, namely [set](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html#cmd-set), overriding variables in [overrides](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables-override), [count](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/count.html#cmd-count) and [for](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/for.html#cmd-for). Their globs are permitted to expand to zero arguments, as with `shopt -s nullglob` in bash.

So you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
converter_to_csv *.ods
set result $status

set csvfiles *.csv
if test (count $csvfiles) -eq 0
    echo "No CSV files produced" >&2
    exit $result
else
    cat $csvfiles >> data.csv
end
```